# how to load Backbone.D3View as a jQuery Backbone replacement

Tags: jquery, d3.js, backbone.js, requirejs, browserify

[Backbone.D3View](https://github.com/akre54/Backbone.D3View) is a dropin replacement for jQuery for manipulating the DOM. However, I'm currently wondering about an initial step in the readme.

> Load Backbone.D3View with your favorite module loader

Backbone is really hands off on implementation and leaves it to the user, but loading/extending `backbone.d3view` isn't immediately apparent to me. For example, requiring `Backbone` with the following is okay with my `browserify` implementation; `Backbone = require("backbone")`, but the same with `D3View` confuses me. Any advice is greatly appreciated! thanks.

```
Backbone = require("backbone")
Backbone.D3ViewMixin = require("backbone.d3view")
_ = require("underscore")
_.extend(Backbone.View.prototype, Backbone.D3ViewMixin)
```

I have a github issue for this here, https://github.com/akre54/Backbone.D3View/issues/7 as well and will close either question when I get an answer, thanks!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

my issue had to do with file structure and order of compilation. The D3View setup is described fine. :)